# Erro no catchError do tutorial Tour of Heroes do Angular 6

Tags: angular

Sou novato no angular, e estou seguindo o tutorial Tour of Heroes do Angular 6 e tendo problemas com o catchError de um Observable. Esse é o erro que o VSCODE me envia:

```
Type 'Observable<{} | Hero[]>' is not assignable to type 
'Observable<Hero[]>'.
  Type '{} | Hero[]' is not assignable to type 'Hero[]'.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Hero[]'.
      Property 'includes' is missing in type '{}'.
```

Meu código não ta completo, mas até esse momento, segundo o tutorial, as coisas deveriam funcionar.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Hero } from './hero';

import { MessageService } from './message.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {



  constructor(private messageService: MessageService,
              private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';

  /** GET heroes from the server */
  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(heroes => this.log(`fetched heroes`)),
        catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
      );
  }

    /** GET hero by id. Will 404 if id not found */
  getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
    const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Hero>(url).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`fetched hero id=${id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Hero>(`getHero id=${id}`))
    );
  }

  private log(message: string) {
    this.messageService.add('HeroService: ' + message);
  }


}
```

Essa é minha classe Hero:

```
export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;    
}
```

Em suma, o resto do código ta OK, tanto que esse erro aconteceu depois que inseri o catchError, porém não to conseguindo a lista de heróis.

Comment: Na linha `catchError(this.handleError<Hero>(\`getHero id=${id}\`))` não seria `catchError(this.handleError(\`getHero id=${id}\`))` ou ``catchError(this.handleError.bind(this, `getHero id=${id}`))`` ?

Comment: Pior que não, o erro continua.

Comment: onde esta o codigo do metodo handleError?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usando o **of**.

```
  /** GET heroes from the server */
  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(heroes => this.log(`fetched heroes`)),
        catchError(()=> of([]))
      );
  }
```